# Swing accelerators : inputMap or menu?

Tags: java, swing

I want to add an accelerator to a component, say undo/redo (Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-Y) to a `JTextComponent`, but would like to show the action and its shortcut command in a `JMenu`, should I add the `KeyStroke` + `AbstractAction` to :

- the `InputMap` of the component,
- to the `JMenu` of the frame containing the component,
- to both ?

What is the pattern recommended in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when is it proper to use an InputMap with accelerators, then ?

The way a menu works is to add bindings to the InputMap/ActionMap for you automatically. So if you want it documented in the menu then you would only ever add it to the menu and not do a manual mapping to the component.

One case when you would add the KeyBinding only to the component is when you need to have different Actions for each component. For example, you might create menu items for "copy", "paste" on text components. But other components like JTable also support copy and paste. In this case you can't have two menu items with the same accelerator so you bind the table Action directly to the table.

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't know everything went through the InputMap / ActionMap. Do you have a link explaining how the menu affects these maps (which I guess are the JFrame's) ? Thank you.

Comment: Read up on Key Bindings (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for general information. For specifics you need to look at the source code. Check out the "updateAcceleratorBinding()" method found in BasicMenuItemUI. The "WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW" InputMap of the menu item is used.

Comment: You could have a single menu item, that checks the focused component and branches to two different actions depending on the type of the focused component.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do both as your description implies then do both.  This is normal.

However, if the undo/redo only applies to just one component out of several on the frame I would not suggest adding it to the frame's menu.  (Although you possibly could create a `JPopupMenu` on the component).

Comment: But doing both, only the inputMap's action is triggered, not the menu's... it doesn't look fine to me, is it just me ? It seems I should just drop the inputMap, considered I want it to show in the menu.

Comment: I would give the same action to both the menu and the input map.

Comment: Ok, but still the action isn't triggered by the menu. The user is "bluffed" : he thinks he is calling the menu item, whereas he's calling the inputMap's action instead (though indeed it is the same Action object)... it just seems kind of weird to me. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have a visible menu item, you would need to use an input map. But when you have a visible menu item, I guess it is a good practice to add accelerators. Use the toolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask() mask to make them work both on Windows and Mac platform.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from a user's point of view: I'd prefer to see shortcuts in the menu (or context menus), because this helps me learning them.

Comment: Sure, I agree with you. But when is it proper to use an InputMap with accelerators, then ?